# grunt-run remove console colors

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a small grunt task to clean my coverage folders, then run my tests like so :

```
grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:test',
    'run:test'
]);
```

The run task itself looks like so :

```
   options: {},
   test: {
        cmd: 'npm',
        args: [
            'test'
        ]
    }
};
```

Note: this is using grunt-run task - https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-run

These tasks do their job just fine, however when run through the grunt task the color is removed from the tests in the console. When I just run npm test, the color is there. I am wondering if there is any way to get around this? After googling a bit, I tried adding to the run task:

```
  options: {
        'no-color': false
  },
```

but this seemed to do nothing. Is there any way to enable the color here? Thanks!

Comment: Need to know which plugin `run` belongs to

Comment: @theaccordance Oh sorry about that, I am using grunt-run  -https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-run

Comment: The plugin doesn't support passing color output into grunt, you'll need to submit a feature request to the author for consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using colors in `grunt.log` if coloring in tests is in your control.,

E.g,

```
var grunt = require("grunt");

grunt.log.writeln("Test failure !"["red"]);

grunt.log.writeln("5 tests failed !"["red"].bold);
```

Comment: I don't see how this applies? It is a grunt-run task running a npm script (running mocha for the tests).

Comment: @ajmajmajma Thats why i had mentioned "if coloring is in your control."  otherwis you can use something like [link]https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-mocha-test instead of using grunt-run (which is not yet started supporting colors by default).

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem and resolve it by configurate grunt task with additional arguments: "--colors"

```
uiTests: {
   cmd: "node",
   args: [
       "node_modules/codeceptjs/bin/codecept.js",
       "run"
       "--steps"
       "--colors"
       ]
  },
```